# Any frameworks to build synchronization solutions?

Tags: .net, data-synchronization

We are going to build multisource master-to-master data synchronization solution.

1. Data will be both file based and structured.
2. Synchronization is on demand
3. Nice to have synchronization orchestration
4. Nice to have conflict resolution strategies

Is there anything to start with? Frameworks, libs, just best practices? I am aware of Microsoft Sync Framework, but it is abandoned since last release in 2010.

Platform is .NET

Answer (score 1):

We started Rethync project ( https://www.eldos.com/rethync/ ) initially for structured data and planned to extend it with file sync later. While Rethync works fine, the demand is low, so the project was not extended to file sync so far.

Rethync comes in complete source code and you can use it freely. We will fix bugs and update the project if anything is reported.